# Docker installation of WordPress Error docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am totally new to Docker and I want to install WordPress on my laptop

```
Details are : 
OS : Windows 10 Home
Docker Version : Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

I am trying to install WordPress using docker-compose.yml and my code is

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
       MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
       MYSQL_USER: admin
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: admin
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

When I am running this

```
 docker-compose up -d
```

I am getting following error

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'wordpress'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see any issues with your compose file. Are you sure you are pasting here what you are actually running?

Comment: yes sir it is the same

Comment: I really doubt it because I tried your compose file and ran the command exactly and didn't get any error.

Comment: how can i share my actual file to you ?

Comment: you don't have to share, open your file in an editor vscode or atom and see if the indentation is correct. This error can happen if the indent is out of order.

Comment: I retyped code and it is working $ docker-compose up -d
wordpress_db_1 is up-to-date
wordpress_wordpress_1 is up-to-date but when I do http://localhost:8000 it is not working why ? pl help

Comment: check if there is another process using your port 8000, using netstat -an

Comment: finally it is working, i used docker using dockertoolbox $ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v19.03.5 and if i give now http://192.168.99.100:8000/ it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Check if your indentation is correct. These errors are reported due to incorrect indentation.